# How to find day of date using only pyspark functions

Tags: pyspark

How to find the day of a date using only Pyspark functions

If date is 13-09-2018 then day will be Wednesday.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([["2018-09-13"]], ["date"])
df.withColumn(
 "day",
 date_function("date")
)
```

Can you please suggest me a date_function for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below solution and let me know if that helps you:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('2015-04-08 13:08:15',)], ['date'])

df = df.withColumn(
    "date",
    F.col("date").cast("date")
)

df.show()

df.withColumn(
 "day",
 F.date_format(F.col("date"), "E")
).show()
```

output for the same is :

```
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2015-04-08|
+----------+

+----------+---+
|      date|day|
+----------+---+
|2015-04-08|Wed|
+----------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks [Ankit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5151912/ankit-kumar-namdeo)